# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymongo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymongo

I have followed this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-package-with-dependency) last year to build my AWS python archive and it was working.

Today i have automated my code deployment and it was not working (i am using         `shutil.make_archive("package", 'zip', root_dir=path, base_dir="package/", verbose=True)` instead of the `zip -r package.zip package/` command now.

But when i start doing all these steps manually again and deploy (without the automated code) it's not working anymore.

Here is what my folders look like :

[image]

[image]

The only thing that has changed since the last time it was working is the pymongo version which was 3.12 instead of 4.3.3.

My handler is :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
```

The error i am getting from CloudWatch :

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymongo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

What am i doing wrong ?

EDIT :

I have found an old dependency package that is working, but that is using more than just `pymongo[srv]` so i will check what may be different but the error comes from the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lambda to find your external dependency, all your dependency must be inside audio-handler folder and not package. By default, lambda looks for dependency in the root directory.

```
audio-handler
 |-bson
 |-pymongo
 .
 .
 .
 |-lambda_function.py
```

Here is the video on how to create your deployment package and deploy it on aws lambda
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtlxf_kn5zY

Comment: Thanks indeed i was zipping the package folder instead of its content recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise that you use a Lambda Layer to import external modules, ensuring your packaged components are at the root of the project and not within a directory named package.

Add External Python Libraries to AWS Lambda using Lambda Layers
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-external-python-libraries-aws-lambda-using-layers-gabe-olokun

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link you provided, but adding the layer didn't change anything i am stil lgetting the error. 
This is so weird as it was working fine last week.. could this come from the dependencies themselves ?
I am installing `pymongo[srv]` as a dependency

Comment: Expose the dependencies under Audio-Handler directory and remove the `packages` directory.